# How we can specify Access Control policy for accessing the SharePoint admin center to only specific IP addresses

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, azure, sharepoint-admin-center

Inside SharePoint admin center >> Access control >> we can restrict access to SharePoint & OneDrvie to only specific IPs, as follow:-

[image]

but can we apply same settings to the SharePoint admin center? so only users from a specific IPs can access the SharePoint online admin center?